# Replace async method with sync version - drawbacks?

Tags: c#, .net, http, methods, async-await

I have an async method for my app which simplifies a HTTP request for my needs:

```
public async Task<string> MyAsyncMethod()
{
  ...

  using (var httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)await req.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
  {
    ...

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
      httpResp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
      return _response = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to make a corresponding non-async method by reusing as much code as possible.

I was thinking of doing the following:

- Rewrite method to sync method (use GetResponse and ReadToEnd instead of async methods)
- Replace ResponseAsync() with a method that references the sync method

But would mean I could ditch my async method altogether and always use my sync method in an async context, which would reduce async-nesting (which is good). I mean in both cases the same operation (e.g. getting a response) is done in an async context anyway, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But would mean I could ditch my async method altogether and always use
>   my sync method in an async context, which would reduce async-nesting
>   (which is good). I mean in both cases the same operation (e.g. getting
>   a response) is done in an async context anyway

That's incorrect. If by *"use my sync method in an async context"* you mean wrapping your synchronous version with `Task.Run` (which is the [async over sync anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)) then that is not the same as using a truely async method. When you use async methods, you're **freeing the calling thread** to do more work while the asynchronous operation is on-going. When your using a sync version, you're doing the opposite, you're **blocking until that method call completes.** When you wrap a blocking method with `Task.Run`, you're actually using *another thread* just to block inside it, because the delegate will be of your sync version.

**Side note:**
Using `HttpClient` can greatly reduce the amount of code you need to offload a request:

```
public Task<string> RequestAsync(string url)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    return httpClient.GetAsStringAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: The httpclient thing is very useful ty

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `async` methods that return `Task` will return immediately, (i.e. will not wait the operation to complete unless you specify explicitly with `await`).

So for your case your method will not change a lot, but maybe the **usage** of your method will differ, because you will not need events to tell you execution is completed; the code continues when it finishes.